# QT write another Thread data in txt file

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to write data from another thread in txt file.
Text files will be named currentTime() and created periodically every minute.
So, Txt file made very well every minute using QTimer, but In Txt file, content is null.
Of course this result is correct. Because i didn't connect data from another Thread.
How to connect or send data from another thread to QTimer make the txt file every minute?
For example, another thread get data every second and QTimer make txt file every minute.
Ideally, another thread get 60 data in minute and one text file made in minute.
I want to write 60 data to txt file one cycle.

mythread.h

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(qintptr ID, QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();

signals:
    void error(QTcpSocket::SocketError socketerror);
    void sendValue(QString strValue);
    void close(QString disconnectId);

private slots:
    void readyRead();
    void disconnected();
    void InitThreadObjects();
    void sendData();

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    qintptr socketDescriptor;
    QByteArray Data;

};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

mythread.cpp

```
#include "mythread.h"

#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTime>
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>

MyThread::MyThread(qintptr ID, QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    this->socketDescriptor = ID;
}

int count = 0;

void MyThread::run()
{
    // thread starts here
    qDebug() << " Thread started";

    socket = new QTcpSocket();

    // set the ID
    if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor))
    {
        // something's wrong, we just emit a signal
        emit error(socket->error());
        return;
    }

    // connect socket and signal
    // note - Qt::DirectConnection is used because it's multithreaded
    //        This makes the slot to be invoked immediately, when the signal is emitted.

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));
    connect(this, &MyThread::started, this, &MyThread::InitThreadObjects);

    // We'll have multiple clients, we want to know which is which
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << "Client connected";

    QString strValue = QString::number(socketDescriptor);

    emit sendValue(strValue);

    // make this thread a loop,
    // thread will stay alive so that signal/slot to function properly
    // not dropped out in the middle when thread dies


    exec();
}

void MyThread::readyRead()
{

    // get the information
    Data = socket->readAll();
    // will write on server side window
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Data in: " << Data;

    socket->write(Data);
}

void MyThread::disconnected()
{
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Disconnected";
    QString disconnectId = QString::number(socketDescriptor);
    emit close(disconnectId);
    socket->deleteLater();
    exit(0);
}

void MyThread::InitThreadObjects(){
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(sendData()));
    timer->start(60000);
}


void MyThread::sendData(){

    QTime currentTime = QTime::currentTime();
    QString time = currentTime.toString("hhmmss");
    QString filename = "/home/pi/"+time+".txt";
    qDebug() << filename;
    QFile file(filename);

    if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not open file for writing";
        return;
    }

    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << Data;
    file.flush();
    file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create QTimer in another thread

```
public slots:
    void InitThreadObjects();
```

and in constructor add initialization

```
connect(this, &Thread::started, this, &Thread::InitThreadObjects);
```

```
void Thread::InitThreadObjects(){
    m_Timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(m_Timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Thread::TimeWriteData);
    m_Timer->start(60 * 1000);
}
```

record the collected data

```
void Thread::TimeWriteData(){
// Write data to file
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I edited my post. As you let me know, i edited my code but it is not working. is there another problem?